# adding Bridge ...losing internet

Tags: ubuntu, bridge

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 , when i added bridge as next:

`-brctl addbr bro
-brctl addif br0 eth0
-brctl addif br0 tap0
-ifconfig br0 up
-dhclient -v br0`

  I lost the internet connection, any clues ?

Comment: Troubleshoot. Do you get an IP address? Do you see traffic on the bridge?

Comment: yes I got new ip for the bridge

Comment: Okay, and can you ping your default gateway by IP address?

Comment: the br0 got an ip ( X.X.X. 50 ) ,  eth0 have already an ip (X.X.X.62) , and i can ping from my ubuntu another machine in my office with ip (X.X.X.63) but i cant connect to the internet .

Comment: What happens when you try to ping machines not on your LAN? Do you get an error? What error?

Comment: Actually even without the bridge i can brows "www.google.com"  but i cant ping it , i do not get any error message , same after i add the bridge I do not revive message after ping but also i cant brows .